# Git merge – Access to: theirs; ours; merged-with-conflicts & nearest-ancestor

Tags: git, merge

During a git merge, where a file requires merging, how can I access the various files that will go in to the merge: ours, theirs, the nearest ancestor, and the merged file with conflict markers?

I know that I can checkout the file with `git checkout --ours`, `git checkout --theirs`, but I'd like some kind of `git cat --theirs <file-name>`. Or even for all the merge participants to be available in folders so I can easily feed them in to other tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [advanced merging documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging) states that you can show stages of conflicting files.

```
$ git show :1:file       # common version
$ git show :2:file       # our version
$ git show :3:file       # their version
```

It's actually a shorthand for looking up the SHA-1.

Comment: That's excellent, thank you! … if I see merge conflict markers in the common version, those will have come from someone making a bad commit, I guess?